# Greek characters, as command-line arguments, not recognized when running project in debug mode

Tags: qt, debugging, unicode, encoding, command-line

Recently i upgraded my Qt Creator version to 4.5.1 from 4.4.(something!).

Up until before upgrade and when i was running my project (always with command-line argument for testing purposes), i had one of the command-line argument be a Greek character string (actually not my project, i' m just continuing others work) which later in the programm i compare it with some fixed strings to decide in which mode the programm is gonna run.

The problem is that when i run the programm in Run mode (Build configuration "Debug" and clicked "Run" (shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) ) the argument is recognized correctly (qDebug-ing it shows the correct Input string) and is properly compared, but when i run in Debug (Build configuration "Debug" and clicked "Start Debugging" (shortcut <kbd>F5</kbd>) ) mode, the argument is not recognized correctly (qDebug-ing it shows the gibberish).

I'm wondering if something "broke" during upgrade or if a setting or something else changed config.